# Sink Drain Leakage

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink

I installed a new lavatory sink drain . All plastic, made up very hand tight but 3 of the 4 threaded connections have a couple drops of water. I lined up all connections before tightening any. I have put in about 8 new sinks over the years and never had this happen. I can tighten more with channel-locks but I am concerned with breaking the plastic. These are all compression or flare connections so should not need pipe dope. What did I miss ?

Comment: Contrary to widespread shared ignorance, slip-joint drain fittings need to be tightened with a wrench. Yes, I have seen plastic *and* metal nuts split, threads damaged, drain pieces damaged; by **overtightening**. Snug them up with channellocks please.

Comment: If you can't get the joints to stop dripping after using a wrench to tighten as Jimmy Fix-it said, then loosen the nuts and put a small amount of silicone (RTV in a tube) on the joints where the plastic joints touch and re-tighten the nuts.

Comment: My first mistake was it was one leak at the bottom of the sink and a few drops of water ran onto the other connections . Second , I did not check the  bottom of the sink before putting in the new drain . The faux marble was pretty rough and the thicker softer gasket on the 10 year old drain had sealed it, but the new gasket would not. I sanded it and put on a little silicone.  .